# domain redirect loop issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am newbie in htaccess. my domain will create redirect loop. i have no idea why this is happening. this is the code

```
RewriteEngine on
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .php .html
IndexIgnore *
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

The same code working fine from a couple of month but now suddenly it creating redirect loop. i have no idea why this is happening.

I want that user will always open in `https` not in `http`

Please make me correct what happing wrong with this code.

Comment: Are you able to provide any further details? If the code hasn't changed, there must be something else effecting the domain.

Comment: i have done nothing the code suddenly creating loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rewrite rules you need to use in order to redirect `http://` to `https://` are:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Pay attention to the `!=on` part: it must stay as written here; if you put a space between `!=` and `on` the Apache server won't start.

Comment: ... or it will respond with `500 Internal Server Error` to the affected requests, if you put the rule in a `.htaccess` file.